# QEMU: get accurate PC when the guest is running

Tags: qemu

I need to access the PC at runtime. For example, an instruction triggers an memory access to an unimplemented periphery, which is captured in hw/misc/unimp.c. However, when I get the pc by reading the current CPUState, what I got is the first instruction of the current translated block (TB). I know this is because of TCG. Do anyone know how to extract the current accurate PC value?

Thank you so much!
Le

Answer (score 1):

I found that [Panda](https://github.com/panda-re/panda) provides a nice solution. Briefly speaking, it allocates a variable representing the precise PC. When translating a guest instruction, the resulting native code also updates this variable using the value of next_pc.